# how to show blank instead of 0 in datagridview c#.net

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a window application Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008. My code is working fine. I need only one thing that if any value is `0.000` in database, it should be shown blank in `DataGridView`. Please, give me solution. Thanks in advance. Code is given below:

```
sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select Item, Cast (Val1 AS DECIMAL (10,3)), Cast (Val2 AS DECIMAL (10,2)), Cast (Val3 AS DECIMAL (10,2)), Cast (Val4 AS DECIMAL (10,3)), sno from Opstk where Vno ='" + txtVno.Text + "'",  con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sdaq.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["Item"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item[2].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item[3].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item[4].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item[5].ToString();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set a `Format` for either the `DataGridView's` global `DefaultCellStyle` , maybe like this:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "###.##";
```

or for the one of a certain column

```
dataGridView1.Columns[yourColumn].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "###.##";
```

**Note** however that you are adding the values **not as numbers but as strings**. This is not necessarily wrong, but it will prevent doing calculations and other things. It will also prevent a numeric format like above to work.

Either add them as numbers (recommended) or simply use the format you want right in the `ToString` function:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString("###.##");
```

But again: Now the numbers are lost and you would have to waste time if you ever want to use them..

Of course you may want to pick some other [numeric format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..

Answer (score 1):

If the value of the grid cell is 0, but you don't want it to display 0, 
you can set the value of the cell to DBNull.Value

```
if( item[1] == 0 ) 
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Later, if you need the 0 value for a calculation, you can reverse

```
int myValue = 0;
if (dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value != DBNull.Value) 
    { myValue = dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: 
`double value = Convert.ToDouble(item["Item"]);
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = value == 0 ? "" : value.ToString();` But this is dirty, you should call `datagridView1.DataSource = yourDataTable;`

Comment: The other way around - if it's 0 in the database it should be blank in the datagrid